# Progress Bar while fetching data from server in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

How to show progress bar while fetching data from database in wp7?

Answer (score 5):

When you are fetching data, set a flag (`bool`) `IsLoading` to `true`. When it's done, set the same flag to `false`. Implement the `onPropertyChanged`-event whenever this is changed.

To show a progress bar, add the following to your `XAML`:

```
<toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar 
       x:Name="performanceProgressBar" 
         IsIndeterminate="true" 
         Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Then you implement a `VisibilityConverter`and to make your `bool` value into a `Visibility`-enum.

There's tons of information about this on the web, so I'm not going to rewrite what others taught me. Have a look at these links:

- http://bit.ly/S1SjTf <-- start here
- http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-PerformanceProgressBar-in-depth
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2010/08/18/windows-phone-applications-downloading-images-and-indeterminate-progressbar.aspx